# Show labels on candlestick plot at designated points

Tags: gnuplot

Given a very simple candlestick plot:

```
$Data << EOD
2020-01-01,74.06,73.19,81.96,77.38
2020-02-01,76.08,64.09,81.81,68.34
2020-03-01,70.57,53.15,76.0,63.57
2020-04-01,61.63,59.23,73.63,73.45
2020-05-01,71.56,71.46,81.06,79.49
2020-06-01,79.44,79.3,93.1,91.2
2020-07-01,91.28,89.15,106.42,106.26
2020-08-01,108.2,107.89,131.0,129.04
2020-09-01,132.76,103.1,137.98,115.81
2020-10-01,117.64,107.72,125.39,108.86
2020-11-01,109.11,107.32,121.99,119.05
2020-12-01,121.01,120.01,138.79,132.69
2021-01-01,133.52,126.38,145.09,131.96
2021-02-01,133.75,118.39,137.88,121.26
2021-03-01,123.75,116.21,128.72,122.15
2021-04-01,123.66,122.49,137.07,131.46
2021-05-01,132.04,122.25,134.07,124.61
2021-06-01,125.08,123.13,137.41,136.96
2021-07-01,136.6,135.76,150.0,145.86
2021-08-01,146.36,144.5,153.49,151.83
2021-09-01,152.83,141.27,157.26,141.5
2021-10-01,141.9,138.27,153.17,149.8
2021-11-01,148.99,147.48,165.7,165.3
2021-12-01,167.48,157.8,182.13,177.57
2022-01-01,177.83,154.7,182.94,174.78
2022-02-01,174.01,152.0,176.65,165.12
2022-03-01,164.7,150.1,179.61,174.61
2022-04-01,174.03,155.38,178.49,157.65
2022-05-01,156.71,132.61,166.48,148.84
2022-06-01,149.9,129.04,151.74,136.72
2022-07-01,136.04,135.66,163.63,162.51
2022-08-01,161.01,157.14,176.15,157.22
2022-09-01,156.64,138.0,164.26,138.2
2022-10-01,138.21,134.37,157.5,153.34
2022-11-01,155.08,134.38,155.45,148.03
2022-12-01,148.21,125.87,150.92,129.93
2023-01-01,130.28,124.17,147.23,144.29
2023-02-01,143.97,141.32,157.38,147.41
2023-03-01,146.83,143.9,165.0,164.9
2023-04-01,164.27,159.78,169.85,169.68
2023-05-01,169.28,164.31,179.35,177.25
2023-06-01,177.7,176.93,194.48,193.97
2023-07-01,193.78,186.6,198.23,196.45
2023-08-01,196.24,171.96,201.73,187.87
2023-09-01,189.49,167.62,189.98,171.21
2023-10-01,171.22,165.67,182.34,170.77
2023-11-01,171.0,170.12,192.93,189.95
2023-12-01,190.33,187.45,196.62,192.53
EOD

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set datafile separator ","
set palette defined (-1 "red", 1 "green")
set style fill solid noborder
unset colorbox

unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
set size 0.9,0.9
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set lmargin at screen 0.1

plot $Data using 0:2:3:4:5:($5 < $2 ? -1 : 1) with candlesticks palette notitle
```

I am trying to create 4 labels:

- one at the very first open value (`2020-01-01,74.06,73.19,81.96,77.38`)
- one at the very last close value (`2023-12-01,190.33,187.45,196.62,192.53`)
- one at the candlestick that has the lowest value (`2020-03-01,70.57,53.15,76.0,63.57`)
- and one the candlestick that has the highest value (`2023-08-01,196.24,171.96,201.73,187.87`)

I am passing data in from an external script so I know these points in advance should it be impossible to calculate them using gnuplot.

Here is a rough illustration of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

That part I am struggling with is specifying x-coordinates since I am dealing with time data. How should I proceed with specifying x-coordinates in this case?

Another one is offsetting the labels properly. With the ones that are on the left and right side of the plot I can use `left` or `right` offset. But how should I proceed with the ones that are at the top and bottom? How do I offset from top and from bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a compact *gnuplot-only* solution which is straightforward, but probably needs some explanations.

Although you can extract min, max values via `stats` (check `help stats`), here it is done during the plotting of the data. Fruthermore, the script doesn't use `set xdata time` and `set timefmt ...`, but `set format x ... timedate` and `timecolumn()`. It also doesn't use a palette for the color, but simply defines the color by hex-code and `lc rgb var` (check `help colorspec`)

- define an array `L[8]` which will store your desired values, i.e. `L[8] = [xfirst, xmin, xmax, xlast, yfirst, ymin, ymax, ylast]`
- define a function `getLabels()` which extracts all above values, but during plotting simply returns the current date `t`. Check `help timecolumn`, `help operators binary` (serial evaluation)  and `help ternary`.
- the array `L` will be plotted with the plotting style `with labels`, but only the first 4 values (`every :::3`), check `help every`. And the y-values are taken from `L[5:8]`.

As you noted, the labels by default will be plotted centered on the point. So, how to shift them appropriately? As far as I know, there is no variable text offset. Well, you could add some offset to the x- and y-values, but then this would depend on the ranges of the axes. You need some offset in characters.

One possible way:

- first you shift all labels up in y-direction by 1 in character units, i.e. `offset 0,1`
- then you define a function (using `sprintf()` and ternary operator) which shifts the labels as desired: `first` to the left, `min` down, `max` stays where it is, `last` to the right.
- left and right is done via adding enhanced text `&{mmmm}` (check `help enhanced`) in front or in the back. You could also use just spaces        , but with proportional fonts you would need quite a few.
- since all labels are offset by 1 in y-direction you need to downshift all of them (except `max`) again simply by adding a `"\n"` in front of the label. `min` requires and extra `"\n"`.

I hope the explanations are sufficient to understand the script below.

**Data:** `SO77892737.dat`

```
2020-01-01,74.06,73.19,81.96,77.38
2020-02-01,76.08,64.09,81.81,68.34
2020-03-01,70.57,53.15,76.0,63.57
2020-04-01,61.63,59.23,73.63,73.45
2020-05-01,71.56,71.46,81.06,79.49
2020-06-01,79.44,79.3,93.1,91.2
2020-07-01,91.28,89.15,106.42,106.26
2020-08-01,108.2,107.89,131.0,129.04
2020-09-01,132.76,103.1,137.98,115.81
2020-10-01,117.64,107.72,125.39,108.86
2020-11-01,109.11,107.32,121.99,119.05
2020-12-01,121.01,120.01,138.79,132.69
2021-01-01,133.52,126.38,145.09,131.96
2021-02-01,133.75,118.39,137.88,121.26
2021-03-01,123.75,116.21,128.72,122.15
2021-04-01,123.66,122.49,137.07,131.46
2021-05-01,132.04,122.25,134.07,124.61
2021-06-01,125.08,123.13,137.41,136.96
2021-07-01,136.6,135.76,150.0,145.86
2021-08-01,146.36,144.5,153.49,151.83
2021-09-01,152.83,141.27,157.26,141.5
2021-10-01,141.9,138.27,153.17,149.8
2021-11-01,148.99,147.48,165.7,165.3
2021-12-01,167.48,157.8,182.13,177.57
2022-01-01,177.83,154.7,182.94,174.78
2022-02-01,174.01,152.0,176.65,165.12
2022-03-01,164.7,150.1,179.61,174.61
2022-04-01,174.03,155.38,178.49,157.65
2022-05-01,156.71,132.61,166.48,148.84
2022-06-01,149.9,129.04,151.74,136.72
2022-07-01,136.04,135.66,163.63,162.51
2022-08-01,161.01,157.14,176.15,157.22
2022-09-01,156.64,138.0,164.26,138.2
2022-10-01,138.21,134.37,157.5,153.34
2022-11-01,155.08,134.38,155.45,148.03
2022-12-01,148.21,125.87,150.92,129.93
2023-01-01,130.28,124.17,147.23,144.29
2023-02-01,143.97,141.32,157.38,147.41
2023-03-01,146.83,143.9,165.0,164.9
2023-04-01,164.27,159.78,169.85,169.68
2023-05-01,169.28,164.31,179.35,177.25
2023-06-01,177.7,176.93,194.48,193.97
2023-07-01,193.78,186.6,198.23,196.45
2023-08-01,196.24,171.96,201.73,187.87
2023-09-01,189.49,167.62,189.98,171.21
2023-10-01,171.22,165.67,182.34,170.77
2023-11-01,171.0,170.12,192.93,189.95
2023-12-01,190.33,187.45,196.62,192.53
```

**Script:**

```
### add labels depending on data
reset session

FILE = "SO77892737.dat"

set datafile separator ","
set style fill solid noborder
set key noautotitle
set format x "%Y\n%b" time
myFmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
set offsets graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.21, graph 0.1

array L[8]   # array to store the label values

getLabels(col) = (t=timecolumn(col,myFmt), $0==0 ? \
    (L[1]=L[2]=L[3]=L[4]=t, L[5]=$2, L[6]=$3, L[7]=$4, L[8]=$5) : \
    (L[4]=t,L[8]=$5),$3<L[6] ? (L[2]=t,L[6]=$3):0, $4>L[7] ? (L[3]=t,L[7]=$4):0, t)

Label(i) = sprintf("%s%s%g%s",i!=3 ? "\n":"", i==4 ? "&{mmmmm}":i==2 ? "\n":"", \
           L[i+4], i==1?"&{mmmmm}":"")

plot FILE u (getLabels(1)):2:3:4:5:($5 $2 ? 0xff0000:0x00ff00) w candle lc rgb var,\
     L every ::::3 u (L[$0+1]):(L[$0+5]):(Label($0+1)) w labels offset 0,1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

The array `L` actually holds the values:

```
[1577836800.0,1583020800.0,1690848000.0,1701388800.0,74.06,53.15,201.73,192.53]
```

[image]